# Exclusive batch processing with fallbacks using RabbitMQ

Tags: php, rabbitmq, php-amqplib

I'm using RabbitMQ in PHP via AMQPLib and RabbitMQ Bundle (for Symfony).

The consumers work on multiple servers, that's what Rabbit is for and that's fine. I encountered however a specific case, where I'd like to read the messages in batches and I'd prefer having only one consumer working at the same time. But in order to achieve high availability I'd like have the the other consumers (from other servers) serving as fallbacks.

What I understand is:

- there is a batch consume option, but as I noticed it doesn't guarantee I receive all the messages in a row to one batch.
- there is `exclusive` flag on Rabbit consume command -- unfortunately the Rabbit bundle doesn't expose it; furthermore if there is an exclusive consumer on a queue, the other one exits with an exception I cannot handle using BatchConsumerInterface

Am I missing something? Is there perhaps some built-in solution allowing me to achieve, what I described above? Without writing complex solutions bypassing the RabbitMQ Bundle?

Comment: So if I understand rightly, what you're looking for is some kind of global lock that a consumer can claim to say "I'm looking at this queue, nobody else look at it unless I disconnect". And then ideally allow other consumers to sleep waiting until they can acquire the lock, rather than exiting. Is that right?

Comment: @IMSoP That's right!